# Blackberry app not able to install on lower version device

Tags: blackberry

I want to install app on blackberry device, problem is that my installed SDK version is higher than the version of blackberry device which i am trying to install, how can i do that?

Comment: Could you tell us which SDK versions are involved here? (the one on the device and the one used to develop the app). Can't you update the device ?

Answer (score 2):

Download the SDK that matches the OS installed on your target device. BlackBerry OS versions are backward compatible, a 5.0 binary will run on OS 7, but not forwards compatible, a 7.0 binary will not run on OS 5.